# Twitter Bootstrap - how to combine form layouts?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `.form-horizontal` to layout my form. I do want the label and form field to align horizontally. However, in some cases, I need multiple form fields to align horizontally. For example, in a form that collects credit card information, I want something like this:

```
          Name:  [___________]
CC Expiry Date:  [____] [____]
```

Is there a way to use `.form-horizontal` on some fields and `.form-inline` for other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mystery, just put your other input together:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  ...
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input1">Label</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Input1">
      <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Input2">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change class `control-group` to `form-inline`

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="control-label">
    <label for="inputCC">CC</label>
    <label for="inputExpiryDate">Expiry Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" id="inputCC" placeholder="CC" class="input-small">
     <input type="text" id="inputExpiryDate" placeholder="Expiry Date" class="input-small">
    </div>  
  </div><br/>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">

      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/md4qz/3/show/)</kbd>